# Find out about RFID type

Tags: rfid

We are using RFID access badges at work. How can I tell what kind of system is at place (frequency, Mifare derivative). I don't have any experience with RFID systems, which one would be the most likely/versatile hardware to start experimentation.

Our badges are in credit card form and have numeric ids with 8 digits.

Background: I want to use the existing access badges to interface our coffee machine. All I need is a unique id from a badge.

Comment: Coffee machine? Seriously?  It sounds like you are really trying to hack the system, and you came up with this coffee machine ruse to make your motivations sound more innocent.

Comment: This is not the first project of this kind. Similar project: http://milwaukeemakerspace.org/2011/10/beer-automated-dispensing-and-security-system/

Comment: Heh, we're doing the same at our hacker space. For us, it was a matter of "let's try if these are Mifare Classic, oh look, there is an app for that." (yes, indeed, there are apps that use a phone's NFC module to speak to Mifare chips and optionally bruteforce their key, which takes about ten minutes)

Answer (score 1):

It is not as simple as that, and most likely your company would look dimly on the security violation.

Most of these types of RFID cards don't just simply send back a fixed number.  That is done in some cost-sensitive applications where only a low level of security is necessary, since these types of systems are easy to hack or to make duplicate keys for.

The types of cards that serve as keys to your company are going to be of the challenge/response type.  The fixed reader sends a random number to the card.  The card applies a hashing algorithm based on the unique key encoded into the card, then returns the hashed result.  The challenge number is long enough so that the chances of the same number being generated twice is very low.  Anyone listening in would therefore only learn the answer to one challenge, which doesn't do any good for responding to future challenges.

Even if someone in your company knew the detailed workings of your key cards, they aren't going to give you the information for you to implement your own lock.

On a separate topic: You want to put a lock on the coffee machine?  Really!?  If your request actually is for the coffee machine, then go find something more important to do.  You're not going to win any office points by showing who was the last to use the coffee machine and didn't refill it.  Again, really!!?

Comment: This does not answer my question how to identify RFID systems. According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608670/mifare-difference-between-uid-and-serial-number-of-mifare-card the UID or Card Serial Number can be read unencrypted.

Comment: @Moe: There are lots of different RFID systems.  The kind used for entry like a key are going to be the more secure type.  Even if we knew exactly what type you have, we're not going to help you break into this company.  There is no legitimate reason for you to know how your company's key cards works or what IDs are on them.

Comment: Please don't make any assumptions about my intent. This is not about breaking into something. As you have pointed out yourself there are very sophisticated systems in place to prevent that. All I want to do is read an id from a card. - If you do not want to help just dont.

Comment: @Moe: You *say* it's not about breaking into something, but of course that is what you'd say either way, so it carries no information. And no, we have every right to consider whether someone might use advice here to do things we don't want to support. Get over it. I note that you still haven't provided the slightest justification as to why a coffee machine needs a key lock. Considering all the things you have said, the probability is quite high you are somehow trying to get away with something. No thanks, not with my help.

Comment: Olin, if you're not going to help him, don't be a dick about it.